# Android Data-binding - Cannot find the getter for attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I used some spinner binding after seeing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39444728/6891563). But i am not able to compile code after that.

Error

> Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'selectedValue' with value type java.lang.String on android.widget.Spinner.
>   file:D:\Khemraj_AndroidStudioWorkspace_\amelioFinal\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_cart.xml
>   loc:167:24 - 175:33
>   ****\ data binding error ****

Pojo

```
public class ViewModel {
    private String text;
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
       this.text = text;
    }
}
```

in xml

```
  <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.amelio.model.ViewModel"/>
```

and

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/days"
            bind:selectedValue="@={viewModel.text}"/>
```

bindingUtil

```
public class SpinnerBindingUtil {

    @BindingAdapter(value = {"selectedValue", "selectedValueAttrChanged"}, requireAll = false)
    public static void bindSpinnerData(AppCompatSpinner pAppCompatSpinner, String newSelectedValue, final InverseBindingListener newTextAttrChanged) {
        pAppCompatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                newTextAttrChanged.onChange();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        if (newSelectedValue != null) {
            int pos = ((ArrayAdapter<String>) pAppCompatSpinner.getAdapter()).getPosition(newSelectedValue);
            pAppCompatSpinner.setSelection(pos, true);
        }
    }
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "selectedValue", event = "selectedValueAttrChanged")
    public static String captureSelectedValue(AppCompatSpinner pAppCompatSpinner) {
        return (String) pAppCompatSpinner.getSelectedItem();
    }

}
```

Comment: i think the `ViewModel` class should have getter and setter for the property I.E.  `setSelectedValue()` and `getSelectedValue()`

Comment: I don't think so, it is an attribute not an variable of model class. And the answer i got has 14 up-vote, strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `android:selectedItemPosition` attribute that supports two-way data binding out of the box. You can use that or use its `BindingAdapter`/`InverseBindingAdapter` pair as a template:

```
@InverseBindingMethods({
    @InverseBindingMethod(type = AdapterView.class, attribute = "android:selectedItemPosition"),
    @InverseBindingMethod(type = AdapterView.class, attribute = "android:selection",
            method = "getSelectedItemPosition",
            event = "android:selectedItemPositionAttrChanged"),
})
```

...

```
@BindingAdapter("android:selectedItemPosition")
public static void setSelectedItemPosition(AdapterView view, int position) {
    if (view.getSelectedItemPosition() != position) {
        view.setSelection(position);
    }
}

@BindingAdapter(value = {"android:onItemSelected", "android:onNothingSelected",
        "android:selectedItemPositionAttrChanged" }, requireAll = false)
public static void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView view, final OnItemSelected selected,
        final OnNothingSelected nothingSelected, final InverseBindingListener attrChanged) {
    if (selected == null && nothingSelected == null && attrChanged == null) {
        view.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
    } else {
        view.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedComponentListener(selected, nothingSelected, attrChanged));
    }
}
```

That would lead me to do something like this:

```
@InverseBindingMethods({
    @InverseBindingMethod(type = AdapterView.class,
                          attribute = "android:selectedValue",
                          method = "getSelectedItem"
})
public class SelectedValueBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("android:selectedValueAttrChanged")
    public static void setSelectedValueListener(AdapterView view,
            final InverseBindingListener attrChanged) {
        if (attrChanged == null) {
            view.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        } else {
            view.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    attrChanged.onChange();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    attrChanged.onChange();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:selectedValue")
    public static void setSelectedValue(AdapterView<?> view, Object selectedValue) {
        Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        // I haven't tried this, but maybe setting invalid position will
        // clear the selection?
        int position = AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            if (adapter.getItem(i) == selectedValue) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        view.setSelection(position);
    }
}
```